How to override default colors in dll library
I am using Windows workflow foundation rehost library in my application and i am trying to override default colors but it is modifying, i tried below code in my application but it is not working.
CustomColors.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1" Source="pack://application:,,,/System.Activities.Presentation;component/System/Activities/Presentation/ColorResources.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WorkflowViewElementCaption" x:Uid="SolidColorBrush_8" Color="#FFE6E6E6" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DesignerViewBackground" x:Uid="SolidColorBrush_9" Color="#FF232325" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LinearGradientBrush" x:Uid="SolidColorBrush_10" Color="#FF232325" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ShellBarBackgroundBrush" x:Uid="SolidColorBrush_11" Color="#FF232325" />
</ResourceDictionary>

and My App.xaml
<Application.Resources>
    
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomColors.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>

My C# Code
    WorkflowDesigner wfDesigner = new WorkflowDesigner();
 wfDesigner.Load(new ActivityBuilder() { });
    designerview.Child = wfDesigner.View;

I found the default color source code in enter link description here
Is there any way to override the default colors.

i ended up with copying the DefaultColorResources.xaml and modified colors and i am loading this file in App.xaml.cs file.
var dyn = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("DesignerViewColors.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
Type type = typeof(WorkflowDesignerColors);
FieldInfo? fieldInfo = type.GetField("defaultColors", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
fieldInfo?.SetValue(null, dyn);


If you look at the theme dictionary, you will see that resources are used using StaticResource. https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.Activities.Presentation/System.Activities.Presentation/Themes/Generic.xaml#L28

Values ​​set in the theme in this way cannot be overridden at runtime (or rather, they can, but require some semi-hacker dancing with a tambourine).
To be able to override, the resource key in the theme must be set using ComponentResourceKey and applied using DymamicResource. See example https://stackoverflow.com/a/78858333/13349759

Thanks for the response all styles under ColorResource.xaml file is referring this file https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System.Activities.Presentation/System.Activities.Presentation/System/Activities/Presentation/DefaultColorResources.xaml is there any way to override this colors? I merged this file with my custom colors in my app.xaml it is not applying my colors it is applying default colors only

@NaveenGolla
To override a resource at runtime, it must be used with DynamicResource. If StaticResource is used, the value is determined at the time of the first call and then fixed for the entire lifetime of the object (including the template or style). You can find all the dictionaries using ColorResource.xaml before the first use and replace Url with your dictionary. But this method will require non-trivial methods of work.

I would advise you to copy all the necessary dictionaries, replace references to DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey in them and use your own dictionaries. This is a much more reliable method than a semi-hackish introduction into existing styles.

Can you pls give me example code

@NaveenGolla
In my answer I gave a link to an answer with an example of using ComponentResourceKey.
